# Android 2d animation using libgdx or default android animation classes

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

what is the difference between Android default animation and Libgdx animation lib.?

which one is better to use for character animation.?

Comment: Libgdx is a graphics library and it provides function for 2d drawing and animations. and the default animation is android provided set of functions for animation.

Comment: Libgdx animation lib will make your animation platform independent but android defult animation will run on android only

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using libgdx, the best one is [Libgdx Animation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html), it will work on all libgdx supported platforms. The Android one will only work on Android. And will be harder to implement, as it is Android specific.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your question you asked what is background thread for AsyncTask, sorry I could not comment because of reputation.

Well, Main thread is the one responsible for your User interface, and sometime also called as UI thread. other threads which does not affect ui directly as don't want to bog your Main thread are called background threads. AsyncTask is well known background thread by all android developers as it allows to update UI data as soon as the data is as ready.

You should use AsyncTask if your task not gonna take more then few seconds, if more time is needed you might consider using FutureTask or Executor Task.